# How do i design/code the color of status bar in eclipse as my android app just like in ios7?

Tags: android, statusbar

I want to design the Android App that will change the status bar of Android device as App opens like in iOS 7.

Can we make status bar changeable in Android?

Comment: Do you mean Status bar as the Action bar ?

Comment: I need to changed the background color of status bar as my app.

Comment: I think, this feature is not possible. I mean, in 4.4, they have made it transparent only on the home screen but not when any app is opened.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no, the status bar in itself cannot be changed in Android by an application.

I guess that to be able to do that you'd need to make a custom ROM or maybe dive into the AOSP and find a way to do that on rooted phones.

Comment: @MarioStoilov Yes but then he'll need to find a way to show all the notification icons